# How to recognize text that looks like a Captcha, but it's not? Using pytesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need to recognize text that looks like this -
[Photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br97r.jpg)
I tried to do it, but some word which is covered by the lines can not be recognized.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('screen.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

text = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="rus")).strip()

print(text)
```

but I got this:

```
Четверо ленов штаба внимательно глядели на Кенн яЗНЫМ

мешком у бедра и с Крючком на длинной лаяк=”- совсем ветхозаветная
—

фигура, что любила эту осеннею`вёткуименно за то, что она

напоминала первой, и аккуратно выкоценный газон, и цветочки, И
баякон. —
```

**I need**:

```
Четверо членов штаба внимательно глядели на Кеннеди, с грязным
мешком у бедра и с крючком на длинной палке — совсем ветхозаветная
фигура, что любила эту осеннюю именно за то, что она
напоминала ей о первой, и аккуратно выкошенный газон, и цветочки. И
балкон.
```

I tried to change the contrast of the image using PIL, but it didn't help.